# jq replace part of value in json

Tags: json, sed, edit, jq, iso8601

I need to replace part of a value from a json output. I could easily do this using `sed -i` however it would also replace other parts of the file I don't want it to, unless I'm missing something. The output is

```
{
  "LastModified": "2018-03-07T17:24:33.000Z",
  "Key": "pending/archive/f7ab1684-e94d-483e-ace1-560367c1196c_1000_s.json"
}
```

and I need to replace the dash "-" on the LastModified value to a slash, then remove some stuff too like the "T" and the ".000Z" So I can eventually convert that timestamp to epoch.

I tried using
`cat list |  jq -r '.[] | select (.LastModified == "-") .LastModified = "/"'`
and `|=` operator but I can't find anywhere else on the web that this has been accomplished.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With **jq**'s `sub()` and `fromdate()` functions:

```
jq '.LastModified |= (sub("\\.000Z";"Z") | fromdate)' input.json
```

The output:

```
{
  "LastModified": 1520443473,
  "Key": "pending/archive/f7ab1684-e94d-483e-ace1-560367c1196c_1000_s.json"
}
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for and worked flawlessly. Can you explain everything thats going on? what does "Z" do?

Comment: Just realized, guessing here, that Z sets the time to UTC?

Comment: @RyanLoeffler, `Z` in datetime strings is universal time (UTC) designator https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=ISO_8601

Answer (score 6):

If your platform supports it, you could use the date functions to parse out then reformat the date string.

```
.LastModified |= (sub("\\.000Z$"; "Z") | fromdateiso8601 | strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

Otherwise, you could use the usual string manipulation techniques.

```
.LastModified |= "\(.[:10] | sub("-"; "/"; "g")) \(.[11:19])"
```

Both results in the results:

```
{
  "LastModified": "2018/03/07 17:24:33",
  "Key": "pending/archive/f7ab1684-e94d-483e-ace1-560367c1196c_1000_s.json"
}
```